# Installed applications have disappeared from add or remove programs in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser-addons

I recently came to notice that most of the softwares and applications that i have installed earlier have disappeared in the add/remove program list. Only things that are left of are Microsoft visual c++ redistributions and some applications that i installed recently.I have scanned my whole computer with an updated avast anti virus for any symptoms of virus. But no threats were found. How could i restore my application list back?

This all happened after i tried to install virtual hotspot plus application which created a lot of trouble by including senses and iWeb add ons to my browsers. I managed to remove them.
What should i do to retrive my list back?

Comment: Sounds like you performed restored from a restore point, is that the case?

Comment: Have the applications actually been removed? Or just not listed? Were they in fact listed prior to this? Have you ran a malware/spyware scan (not just antivirus)?

Comment: do simple tests try running System file checker,otherwise open command prompt as administrator and run SFC /SCANNOW and allow to complete. Restart and test.

Comment: I have tried all types of tests. I took restore point also. It listed all the installed applications then.Later  i was able to see that iWeb and senses were again present in my system  again. so i tried to uninstall them . And now I again see no entry in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve this issue?
If not, try this out:
[Most programs not visible in Programs and Features in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/884192/most-programs-not-visible-in-programs-and-features-in-windows-7)

In my scenario, it seemed to be cause by viruses or malware. Many programs were missing from the uninstall list. I had to go through each one in the registry and correct certain values to restore the list.